# Merge Count Plot and Mean in same plot SNS

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to create a count plot and also add another plot on it which would actually be the mean of the other columns.

The sample data is in the below link:
[Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tn_oSeJrhsr4tQB4Zf9M4aydiUTsDOXp/view?usp=sharing)

I have used the below code to create the sns count plot:

```
df = pd.read_csv("latestfile.csv")
df.sort_values(by=["Business"],inplace=True)
sns.countplot(data=df,x=df["Business"],hue="location")
```

and I generate the below:

[image]

Now I use the groupby and use the below code to get the desired data:

```
dfg = df.groupby(["Business","location"])['Ageing'].mean().reset_index()
dfg.set_index("Business",inplace=True)
```

but how do I plot this on the same count plot on the different y axis.

Unable to think of a way to do it.

Below is what I am finally looking for:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what plot do you want ? Your question is nor so much clear.

Comment: I am looking for a type of line plot which connects the means of the ageing for each of the bars.

Comment: Also how can I plot a scatter plot for Ageing on each of the columns ? I think that would make more sense instead of plotting the mean.

Comment: I suggest you first sort out what your desired outcome is and then ask the question.

Comment: I am ok with either of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can squeeze another bar plot into the countplot graph:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df.sort_values(by=["Business"],inplace=True)
ax1 = sns.countplot(data=df, x="Business", hue="location", palette="muted", edgecolor="black")
for patch in ax1.patches:
    patch.set_x(patch.get_x() + 0.3 * patch.get_width())
ax1.legend(title="Count")

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.barplot(data=df, x="Business", y="Ageing", hue="location", palette="bright", ci=None, ax=ax2, edgecolor="white")
ax2.legend(title="Ageing")

ax1.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, I would definitely prefer two subplots:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df.sort_values(by=["Business"],inplace=True)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))

sns.countplot(data=df, x="Business", hue="location", ax=ax1)
ax1.legend(title="Count")

sns.barplot(data=df, x="Business", y="Ageing", hue="location", ci=None, ax=ax2)
ax2.legend(title="Ageing")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Since you prefer now the distribution, you can combine the countplot with a stripplot:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df.sort_values(by=["Business"],inplace=True)

ax1 = sns.countplot(data=df, x="Business", hue="location")

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.stripplot(data=df, x="Business", y="Ageing", hue="location", jitter=True, dodge=True, ax=ax2, linewidth=1)

ax1.legend(title="", loc="upper center")
ax2.legend_.remove()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking of a line which would connect the mean of the each bar.

Comment: Based on your comment that you prefer the distribution of "ageing" instead of the mean I have updated the answer.